# seleccionar una paleta de colores

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos y estoy haciendo histogramas.
Necesitaría cambiar la paleta de colores. Me gustaría poner un color con distintas tonalidades.

```
ggplot()+
    geom_histogram(mapping= aes(x = edgest_nac, fill = mort_total), breaks = c(23:35))+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")+
    ylab(NULL)+
    xlab(NULL)+
    labs(fill = NULL)+
```

esto es lo que he estado usando. cambio la paleta a set1, set2 o set3 pero no me terminan de gustar las combinaciones.

Comment: Hola Natalia, ¿qué es lo que buscas? ¿distintas tonalidades? eso no tiene mucho sentido en un histograma, ya que este tipo de gráfica solo tiene una sola dimensión y es la altura de cada barra. Por supuesto puedes cambiar el color de todas las barras, pero no entiendo que sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Buenas, he conseguido lo que quería poniendo en vez de "Set3" , por ejemplo, "Oranges".!! Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

A mi me gustan los colores por defecto, pero cuando quiero (o me piden) colores RGB específicos utilizo la librería colourpicker

https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/colourpicker/vignettes/colourpicker.html

Al instalarlo, install.packages("colourpicker") te aparece en RStudio en la pestaña de "Addins".